# Modify topbar between fragments of same activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying with several ways of getting this and not truly achieving it.
What i want is simple, different fragments show different Topbars(or appbars, or toolbars) with different titles and options. As shown here:

[image: topbar1]
[image: topbar2]

Which is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I wasnt navigating to the main fragment so it was never executing the onCreate method properly as the topbar wasnt created yet

Answer (score 1):

Its Quite easy. Set your toolbar inside your fragment xml code and call every different fragment in our one fragment container.

thus you will be able to create different toolbar for different fragment.

Comment: Shouldnt the toolbar be defined in the activity? I mean, redefining the toolbar in each fragment xml doesnt sound good

Comment: Then go for programmatically change on toolbar. use if/else to check your fragment id and then set title,icon,menu.

hope this would help

Comment: From the activity? I am trying to do this from the fragment with
Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.homeTopBar);
 toolbar.setTitle("Home");
on the onCreate method, but the findViewById returns NULL

Comment: ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle();  try this

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

:(

Comment: Use AppCompat Toolbar Instead of AndroidX Toolbar

Comment: Just define multiple toolbars in your fragment. It's not optimal, but it is a perfect valid usecase, if the toolbar changes too much